# How to show if a donation occured in the prior year but not current?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a year-over-year donation report with the following schema & query in Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE Donation
(
   HouseholdID INT, 
   HouseholdName VARCHAR(150), 
   [Donation] REAL, 
   DateOrdered DATE
);

INSERT Donation VALUES
(1,'The Smiths',50,'2011-01-01'),
(1,'The Smiths',75,'2012-02-02'),
(2,'The Wilsons',10,'2011-03-01'),
(2,'The Wilsons',60,'2011-07-01'),
(3,'The Kellys',500,'2012-06-01');

--Params
DECLARE @RunYear   INT=2012
DECLARE @PriorYear INT=@RunYear-1

SELECT 
    [HouseholdID],[HouseholdName],YEAR(DateOrdered) [Year], MAX(Donation) [MaxGift], SUM(Donation) [TotalDonated]
FROM 
    Donation 
WHERE 
    YEAR([DateOrdered]) IN (@RunYear,@PriorYear)
    GROUP BY HouseholdID, [HouseholdName], YEAR(DateOrdered)
    ORDER BY HouseholdID, YEAR(DateOrdered)
```

I'd like to add a `BIT` column like [DonatedInPriorYearOnly] that would be 1 only if the household had a donation in the prior year (2011) but none in the run year (2012).

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select blah, blah, blah
from donation
where householdid in 
(select householdid
from donation
where year(dateordered) = @runyear -1
except
select householdid
from donation
where year(dateordered) = @runyear )
```

That's the logic.  If you want it to run faster, create a set of dates to co-incide with the 1st and end of each year and use those instead of year(dateordered)

**Edit below**

To have a bit column based on this logic, do this.

```
select blah, blah, blah
, case 
when householdid in 
(select householdid
from donation
where year(dateordered) = @runyear -1
except
select householdid
from donation
where year(dateordered) = @runyear )
then 1 else 0 end nameofcolumn
from donation
where whatever
```

Comment: Sounds right. But how do you make that a BIT column in the existing query. I don't want to filter my query but add a column with that info.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your version of SQLServer, you can wrap the summary query (in a subquery or CTE) and use [LAG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx). If HouseholdID and Year don't match LAG HouseholdID and (Year - 1) then there was not a donation in the previous year.

Something roughly like this (untested):

```
SELECT [HouseholdID], [HouseholdName], [Year], [MaxGift], [TotalDonated]
      ,CASE WHEN YEAR = previous_year +1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DonatedPreviousYear

   FROM ( SELECT [HouseholdID], [HouseholdName], [Year], [MaxGift], [TotalDonated]
                ,LAG(Year, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY HouseholdID ORDER BY Year) AS previous_year

            FROM ( SELECT [HouseholdID],[HouseholdName],YEAR(DateOrdered) [Year], MAX(Donation) [MaxGift], SUM(Donation) [TotalDonated]
                     FROM  Donation 
                     WHERE [DateOrdered] BETWEEN @StartDt AND @EndDt
                     GROUP BY HouseholdID, [HouseholdName], YEAR(DateOrdered)
                     ORDER BY HouseholdID, YEAR(DateOrdered)
                  )
        )
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the LAG function. I didn't know this existed.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about LAG either. It's not quite the solution though. I'm not looking for if they donated in the previous year but for each record if that household donated in 2011 but not 2012.

Comment: If you want to look forward rather than back, then use LEAD rather than LAG. Just note that your first LAG value or your last LEAD value in the window will be NULL, so you will need to use COALESCE on the column before doing comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You could `OUTER APPLY` a `SELECT TOP` query to find any donations made by each family in the previous year.

```
SELECT 
     <your select list>
    ,ISNULL(lastyear.donated_bit,0) AS donated_last_year
FROM Donation AS d
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 1 AS donated_bit
    FROM Donation AS d_lastyear
    WHERE d_lastyear.HouseholdID = d.HouseholdID
        AND DATEPART(year, d_lastyear.DateOrdered) = @RunYear - 1
        AND d_lastyear.Donation IS NOT NULL
        AND d_lastyear.Donation > 0
) AS lastyear
```

Comment: Great! Except I think lastyear.donated_bit  will actually give you 1 if the household donated in 2012 and NULL otherwise. I think if you COALESCE the value to make NULL a 0 and then reverse it so 0=1 and 1=0 it would be right.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work it out after reviewing the various suggestions.

```
[DonatedPriorYearOnly] = 
(
   CASE
   WHEN EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT HouseholdID FROM Donation d2
      WHERE YEAR(d2.DateOrdered)=@PriorYear AND d2.HouseholdID=d.HouseholdID
      EXCEPT
      SELECT HouseholdID FROM Donation d3 
      WHERE YEAR(d3.DateOrdered)=@RunYear AND d3.HouseholdID=d.HouseholdID

   )
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
)
```

Thank you everyone for the responses. They were all helpful.